# Execution error on a C++ program: static executable calls DLL library

Tags: c++, dll, static, g++

I'm getting an execution error when trying to run a C++ program compiled with g++ 4.8.1 using `-static` flag in Windows 8.1. When I compile it, I use the following structure:

```
g++ CPP_FILES H_FILES -std=c++11 -O3 -static -I "C:\...\Path_to_include_directory" -L "C:\...\Path_to_library_directory -l library -o PROGRAM.exe
```

Since I want a static compilation, library name is `libgsl_dll_d` (while it's real name is **libgsl_dll_d.lib**).

There are no compilation errors, and then it breaks in execution. Message error says that **libgsl_d.dll** is not in the system. Why that message? I'm not calling that library, and by the way, it is not supposed to be statically compiled? there should be no dependencies in the executable.

I must say that I don't get any error at all when compiling and running this software in Linux Ubuntu 14.04.

Any ideas? I know that it's not possible that a static executable calls dynamic libraries. Why that error? How to solve it?

Comment: Is libgsl_dll_d.lib a DLL's import library?

Comment: ***it is not supposed to be statically compiled?*** No. libgsl_dll_d.lib is an import library. This will require the dll. `.lib` is used for both static libraries and import libraries.

Comment: So, that means that I will need to call that `.dll` library in execution anyway? Then I guess that changing `PATH` environmental variable should solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-static` will cause the linker to prefer static libraries over dynamic ones. But it will not convert a DLL to a static library. Normally it's used when you have both static and dynamic versions of the same library already.

It looks like your file `libgsl_dll_d.lib` is a DLL import library. The purpose of a DLL import library is to allow a DLL to be used like a static library. It is not a static version of the DLL. So it's not surprising that when you link with it, it ends up using the DLL!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and your explanation. I've understood it, and the problem is finally solved.